# Date difference in standalone java vs tomcat server

Tags: java, date, tomcat, utc, xmlgregoriancalendar

I'm having issues converting the date into UTC, I'm able to get this working on a standalone java program, however, while running the same method on a server gives me a different timestamp.

Here is the method I've to convert a String date into XMLGregorianCalendar in UTC.

```
public static XMLGregorianCalendar convertDateToXMLGregorianCalendarInUTC(String date, String dateFormat) throws ParseException, DatatypeConfigurationException {
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(date))
        return null;
    TimeZone timeZoneInUTC = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT0:00");
    GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar = new GregorianCalendar(timeZoneInUTC);
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    Date dateUtil = null;
    XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregorianCalendar = null;

    dateUtil = dateFormat.parse(date);
    gregorianCalendar.setTime(dateUtil);        
    xmlGregorianCalendar = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gregorianCalendar);

    return xmlGregorianCalendar;
}
```

With the above method when I run it on standAlone java prog. It converts the timestamp into UTC by adding 5 hours to the date passed.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, DatatypeConfigurationException { 

    System.out.println("DateUtil xmlGC in UTC: "+DateUtil.convertDateToXMLGregorianCalendarInUTC("03/06/2017 05:47:37", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));

}
```

**OutPut**: `DateUtil xmlGC in UTC: 2017-03-06T10:47:37.000Z.`

However, while using the same method on tomcat - application server on the same machine, it not converting the date into UTC. Am I missing something here.,

Can someone please help me on this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How do you check that tomcat version does not convert date? Using logs?

Comment: @DmitryGorkovets: Yes, I'm logging it, in my application logs.

Comment: What time does your machine return when `date`? The `+0` or `+5`?

Comment: @jlordo: Second code snippet is the standAlone java program I'm talking about., it working fine, it's not working while I'm using the same method while running on an app server.

Comment: @SergioLema: while running on app server it returns me +0., returns me the same exact date I passed.

Comment: Have you tried to use `TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneId zoneId)` instead of passing a `String`? This way you let the application calculates the hours difference

Comment: @SergioLema: I'm on Java 7., can't update now. :(

Answer (score 0):

Set Tomcat timezone
`-Duser.timezone=GMT+05`

Comment: I don't think that would be a good idea., If this is a utility method, anyone using this method would have to update their tomcat timezone. 

There should be a better way to handle this.

Comment: FYI., this didn't help :(